# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] and PDO::__construct()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

i have been trying to make a connection with pdo and keeps giving error.

my code is

```
try {

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost".DBHOST.";port=3306;proflab=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}
```

and the erros are

Warning: PDO::__construct(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginregister-master\includes\config.php on line 21

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Este anfitrião não é conhecido.

Answer (score 2):

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost".DBHOST.";port=3306;proflab=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

You're generating `localhostFOO`, which doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

Connection string is incorrect:

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't that

```
host=localhost".DBHOST."
```

be

```
host=".DBHOST."
```

without "localhost"?